# Match based on String Length

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data similar to:

[image]

My goal to to:

- find the longest string in column **A**
- retrieve the value in column **B** on the same row

so in the above example I want *Juliet*. If there is more than one cell in column **A** having maximum length, then I need to match the first occurrence.

I can do this easily with a *helper* column.  In **C1** I could enter `=LEN(A1)` and copy down; then use `=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAX(C:C),C:C,0))`, but the user does not want a helper column.

Comment: +1 for forcing me into typing out a line from the jabberwocky.

Comment: No love for Hamlet's speech to the players?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, no need for a helper column, just one array function:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAX(LEN(A:A)),LEN(A:A),0))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, of course :)

[image]